# Enigmarch Day 1: Initial

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle was created as part of [Enigmarch](https://enigmarch.com/), a daily puzzle construction challenge.</sub>

---

*Here is no thoughtful hint.*

```
②④_ machine
_⑦___ language
⑧⑤_ party
_⑨_ virus
⑥⑪_ network
⑫⑩_ display
__① test
③__ code
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This puzzle is about:

> acronyms that are often used redundantly, like "PIN number" (which stands for "personal identification number number").

Using this, the blanks can be filled in:

> **ATM** machine
>  **COBOL** language
>  **GOP** party
>  **HIV** virus
>  **LAN** network
>  **LCD** display
>  **SAT** test
>  **UPC** code
>
>  (These answers are in alphabetical order, which helps to confirm that they are correct, and fill any gaps.)
>
>  Then, the numbered circles spell out the answer, **TAUTOLOGICAL**.